# Preferred statistics technique for housing price comparison

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, difference-in-difference, social-science

I'm a college student looking to compare housing prices between some control group of cities and my so-called "treatment" group of cities. More specifically, I'm looking to see if there is a significant difference between increases in housing prices in major Chinese cities versus similar, non-Chinese East Asian cities within a specific time period.

I considered using a 2x2 diff-in-diff method to measure the difference; however, I'm not sure this approach would work particularly well since I don't exactly have a "treatment" I am looking to measure between the two periods. I am also considering creating two regression models between Chinese and non-Chinese housing prices and computing the difference between the slopes. Does anyone with a better statistical background than myself have any other suggestions for possible methods? Thanks!